# How can I catch and log all errors?

Tags: swift

I'm using some third-party functions, and I don't know what types of errors they can produce.

I want to catch and log all such errors, but ErrorType protocol does not have any members that could provide a meaningful message or error code. What can be done to log any type of errors properly?

```
do {
    try someFunction() 
} catch WellKnownError { // handle it }
} catch let err {    
    let message = ... // how can I get error type and some meaningful message from err?
    NSLog(message)    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not an option...

But you can try something like this...

```
//----------------------------------------
// Private API
//----------------------------------------

public enum CarError : ErrorType
{
    case NeverTurnOn
    case OutOfFuel
    case Other(String)
}

public class Car
{

    public func turnOn(newState:Int) throws -> Bool
    {

        if newState == 1
        {
            throw CarError.NeverTurnOn
        }
        else if case 2...5 = newState
        {
            throw CarError.OutOfFuel
        }
        else if newState == 10
        {
            throw CarError.Other("Something is gonna wrong")
        }
        else if newState == 11
        {
            throw CarError.Other(":(")
        }

        return false
    }

}
```

Error Handling

```
func main()
{

    let car = Car()

    do {
        try car.turnOn(4)
    } catch CarError.NeverTurnOn {
        print("Turn off")
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.description)
    } catch {
        print("It's madness!!!")
    }

}

main()
```

With this test... I had this result...

```
//Error Domain=trycatchtest.CarError Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (trycatchtest.CarError error 1.)"
//Program ended with exit code: 0
```

It's not the best way to solve your problem, but a new way to understand what is happening in background of this framework.

Now, asking a favor.

Please, let me now about the final result ;)

It's doesn't matter if is a good or bad result.